# How pass log4j2.xml to Tomcat application

Tags: java, log4j2, tomcat8

I have application which is running at Tomcat 8 server.
Application use log4j2 for internal logging.
I want to have one application.war and two different log config files like:
log4j2_dev.xml and log4j2_prod.xml depending from environment.

In production environment I want deploy application.war and use log4j2_prod.xml
And in development environment  I want deploy application.war and use log4j2_dev.xml

So, how could I specify which file to use during application.war deploying?

PS.
I don't want build two different wars like
application_prod.war and application_dev.war with different configs inside.

Comment: Did you check the [_"Automatic Configuration"_ section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) of Log4j documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` file I've added the line:

```
export LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE=/dev/log4j2_dev.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could specify in your build which config file to use?

E.g. -Dlog4j.configurationFile={path to file}, where path would be determined by building dev or prod?

Comment: Yes: in $CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh (or setenv.bat)

Comment: It defiantly works.
to $CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh I've added line:
export LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE=/dev/log4j2_dev.xml